# Unable to inject EntityManager into Twig extension

Tags: symfony

I have a problem injecting the EntityManger into a Symfony2 twig-extension. I did the following:

I registered a new twig extension and created a class. All of it is working.
Now I wanted to get access to the database and tried to inject the doctrine EntityManager. My first step was to add the EM as parameter to the constructor:

```
use XYZ\BlubBundle\Utils\SessionHelper;

class SessionHelperExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $em;
    private $conn;
    protected $sessionHelper;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, \XYZ\BlubBundle\Utils\SessionHelper $sessionHelper) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->conn = $em->getConnection();
        $this->sessionHelper = $sessionHelper;
    }

    [...]
}

?>
```

Then I added the following lines to the service.yaml:

```
twig.extension.sessionHelper:
    class: XYZ\BlubBundle\Extensions\SessionHelperExtension
    arguments: [@session_helper, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

My own Service "sessionHelper" gets injected without a problem, but the EntityManager is always "null". What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I get the following exception:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
XYZ\BlubBundle\Extensions\SessionHelperExtension::__construct() must be an instance of
Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, 
called in /.../Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2918 and 
defined in /.../Symfony/src/XYZ/BlubBundle/Extensions/SessionHelperExtension.php line 12
```

Answer (score 2):

```php
public function __construct(
    \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, 
    \XYZ\BlubBundle\Utils\SessionHelper $sessionHelper
) {
```

is wrong — you need to keep the same order like in the `yml`:

```php
public function __construct(
    \XYZ\BlubBundle\Utils\SessionHelper $sessionHelper, 
    \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em
) {
```

### Update

Try this: http://www.coderelic.com/2012/06/querying-the-database-from-a-twig-extension-in-symfony-2/

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but even then it is not working. It was just one of my desperate tries to get it working to swap the parameters and so on.

Comment: So try to inject the container and get the EntityManager from the container

Comment: Thanks for all your help. After a long debugging session I found a second "service.yml" which I created a long time ago and it caused all the problems. It was just a typical facepalm-situation. Now everything works fine. As usual PEBKAC :-)

Comment: Yaml's overwriting is terrible!